# package name not observed by sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I compiled a small Scala example of Spark program called AverageAgeByName.scala

Here is the build.sbt:

```
$ cd /opt/LearningSparkV2-master/chapter1/main/scala/chapter3
$ vim build.sbt
// Name of the package
name := "main/scala/chapter3"
// Version of our package
version := "1.0"
// Version of Scala
scalaVersion := "2.12.14"
// Spark library dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.1.2",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.1.2"
)
```

I ran the command:

```
$ sbt clean package
[info] Updated file /opt/LearningSparkV2 master/chapter1/main/scala/chapter3/project/build.properties: set sbt.version to 1.5.5
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.5 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_242)
[info] loading project definition from /opt/LearningSparkV2-master/chapter1/main/scala/chapter3/project
[info] loading settings for project chapter3 from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to main/scala/chapter3 (in build file:/opt/LearningSparkV2-master/chapter1/main/scala/chapter3/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 4, 2021 10:07:27 AM
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to /opt/LearningSparkV2-master/chapter1/main/scala/chapter3/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[success] Total time: 9 s, completed Aug 4, 2021 10:07:36 AM
```

The resulting class was not placed in proper directory hierarchy according to the package name in build.sbt:

```
$ ls /opt/LearningSparkV2-master/chapter1/main/scala/chapter3/target/scala-2.12/classes
'AverageAgeByName$$typecreator1$1.class'  'AverageAgeByName$.class'   AverageAgeByName.class
```

It's flat. I expect the class should be placed in /opt/LearningSparkV2-master/chapter1/main/scala/chapter3/target/scala-2.12/classes/main/scala/chapter3

Where did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name := "main/scala/chapter3"` in the *build.sbt* has nothing to do with a package or a destination folder: it's the name of the project which will be used when packaging your project as a JAR for instance.

The folder in which the classes are generated is driven by the `package` you set in your Scala file *AverageAgeByName.scala*.

The following would generate class file in *target/scala-2/classes/xxx/yyy*:

```scala
package xxx.yyy

class AverageAgeByName {}
```

Also note that usually source files are also put in a directory structure matching the package you set. That is in *src/main/scala/xxx/yyy* in the example above.

And last, you should probably not care at all of where the class files are generated.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you!